# Rails migration namespace with underscore

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model

```
class WorldCup::UploadRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Its path is `model/world_cup/upload_record.rb`.

I want to add a column to it. I tried

```
class AddPhotoToUploadRecord < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :world_cup_upload_records, :photo, :string
  end
end
```

But that doesn't work. What's the correct name of the database?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick ;)

```
class AddPhotoToUploadRecord < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column "#{WorldCup::UploadRecord.table_name.intern}", :photo, :string
  end
end
```

After reading out comments I see you may facing quite different problem.

Either:

1. You're doing Single Table Inheritance, where you have one parent class and one or more inheriting classes and your table has obligatory column named `type`. Then `:lottery_records` will be correct output.
2. You just want to share or encapsulate business logic of your application nad use inheritance. Then you need to put `self.abstract_class = true` into your `LotteryRecord` AR class definition, so the `WorldCup::UploadRecord` will share a logic of `LotteryRecord` but not the table.
   Finally, depending on what you've done so far with your application, `:lottery_records` may or may not be a correct output you seek.

I suggest reading some docs about STI in Rails in order to better understand of what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: Actually this model is inherited from another model called LotteryRecord. The code is `class WorldCup::UploadRecord < LotteryRecord`. I typed `WorldCup::UploadRecord.table_name.intern` in the console, and the output is `:lottery_records`, which means it just add a column to the parent model. Can I just add the column to `WorldCup::UploadRecord` itself without affecting `:lottery_records`?

Comment: Good to know, but the code above should still work. If it doesn't please post your error log.

Comment: Sorry the last comment is halfway done... Please check out my edited comment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I tried `self.abstract_class = true`, but in that way `:lottery_records` cannot be initialized any more. Can I make both `WorldCup::UploadRecord` and `:lottery_records` initializable?

Comment: Yes, but they need to have separate tables or you have to follow STI pattern. In other words, just declaring for example `class AmericaCup::UploadRecord < LotteryRecord` doesn't create a new table for `AmericaCup` automatically. You need to create a migration as well. In order to better uderstand that, type `rails generate model AmericaCup` in your command shell. You'll see that appropriate migration file is being created. Also check here for setting tables explicitly for AR models: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name-3D